# Retain a window created in a callback

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, automatic-ref-counting

I'm wondering what's the correct way to spawn a bunch of windows from a callback, basically i'd like to hit a combination like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> and create a new window, which is not bound to the app delegate. Currently i have the following code in my `AppDelegate.m`:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
    NSLog(@"Finished");

    [NSEvent addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:NSEventMaskKeyDown handler:^(NSEvent *event) {
        NSUInteger ctrlPressed  = [event modifierFlags] & NSEventModifierFlagControl;
        NSUInteger shiftPressed = [event modifierFlags] & NSEventModifierFlagShift;
        NSUInteger cmdPressed   = [event modifierFlags] & NSEventModifierFlagCommand;

        NSUInteger EqButton   = 0x30;

        if (ctrlPressed && shiftPressed && cmdPressed) {
            if ([event keyCode] & EqButton) {
                __strong ETTimerController *controller = [ETTimerController new];
                [controller showWindow: self];
            }
        }
    }];
}
```

This snippet creates a controller and a bound nib file, but i can't see the window, i assume it's collected by the ARC. How can i retain create and retain a new window without storing the reference within the `AppDelegate` instance?

Answer (score 1):

Not only the window, but I think the window *controller* is being released here once the block exits.

Store it in a strong property of `AppDelegate`:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) timerController *ETTimerController;
```

Then, instantiate it like this:

```
self.timerController = [ETTimerController new];
[self.timerController showWindow: self];
```

---

**EDIT:** As mentioned in the comments, the window controller reference needs to be owned by some persistent object (or be a static variable somewhere) otherwise it goes out of scope as soon as the method exits and ARC deallocates the object.
If you can't afford a dedicated property in the AppDelegate class (because you need to have a variable number of different window controllers, etc.), then **you will need to consider what is the expected lifetime of each controller**, and store a reference accordingly:

- If your window controller is *reused*, i.e. its window is repeatedly shown and hidden but you only need at most one, make it a **singleton** and the static reference to the shared instance will take care of retaining it.
- If you are building a [document-based app](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/DocBasedAppProgrammingGuideForOSX/Introduction/Introduction.html), each instance of your NSDocument subclass will create all its window controllers within the `makeWindowController()` method, and retain them inside an array property.
- If none of the above apply, you will need to think of something else that -again- will vary depending on your needs and specifications.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to help me with this! I guess that was the point of my question, how to avoid storing a reference in the AppDelegate. This is a simplified example of course and i need to create multiple windows this way.

Comment: If you don’t store references to your windows controllers *somewhere*, they **will** be deallocated. I have used two patters before to avoid this: 1) Document based app: the document retains the controllers by virtue of `makeWindowControllers()`, and 2) The window controller is a singleton (e.g., Inspector window).